# JPA relationship and Inheritance configuration

Tags: jpa, inheritance

Here are the example:

```
Class Person
Interface Address
Class EmailAddress
Class HomeAddress
Class OfficeAddress
```

The annotation for class Person

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Persson")
```

there are property -- address in Person

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "person")
private Address address
```

and for Interface Address. address is an interface. I don't want to create a table in db. and I hope it's sub class has it's own table

the annotation in class is

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

and the property-- person is

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Person.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
```

but it don't work. 
when I change the address annotation to

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

it work, but it will create a new table.

My question is how can make it work without creating a table of Address? I only need three table, EmailAddress, officeAddress and homeAddress, and I don't want person know three class?

Comment: Address is an interface

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake, and I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are trying to use InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS I am guessing the issue is that you are trying to use Inheritance when there is no relationship at the Database level, viz. in the database there is no relationship between Home Address and Office Address.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses

> Mapped superclass inheritance allows inheritance to be used in the
>   object model, when it does not exist in the data model. It is similar
>   to table per class inheritance, but does not allow querying,
>   persisting, or relationships to the superclass. Its main purpose is to
>   allow mappings information to be inherited by its subclasses.

In this case then you would need to use only the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation on Address and remove all @Inheritance annotations. As noted above, `@MappedSuperclass` cannot be the target of an association. so you cannot have:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
private Address address
```

but would need to do

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
private HomeAddress homeAddress

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
private OfficeAddress homeAddress
```

With regard to interfaces, the JPA spec notes that:

> The entity class must be a top-level class. An enum or interface must
>   not be designated as an entity

Comment: how to configure the Person. I want Person can have a relationship with Address only.

Comment: As clearly stated, person cannot have a relationship with Address if Address is a MappedSuperclass only. What is the table structure of the 2 address tables?

Comment: Can you change the database schema?

Comment: no. Currently I change Address to a abstract class, it can work. it's only for study if Address is a interface, it still can work.